# Ubuntu insserv rejected the script header

Tags: software-installation, init, init.d

I m constantly getting this error while I m trying to install or purge any packages -

```
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

The full log is like -

```
Removing clamav-freshclam (0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for clamav-freshclam (0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99selinux' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'selinux' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service selinux and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service selinux at depth 2
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service selinux and rc.local if started
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package clamav-freshclam (--purge):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
clamav-daemon
 clamav-freshclam
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: First file a bug report. Second see http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/ for how to handle broken packages

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the file **selinux** located at **/etc/init.d** and no problems thereafter.

It was showing in the errors as in the question -

```
insserv: Starting selinux depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
```

Comment: Deleting the selinux script may cause two problems. 1) selinux may not start at boot anymore. 2) uninstalling or upgrading the selinux package may throw an Error (file not found). It's usually better to merely edit the LSD Header tags to eliminate the loop or conflict.